# Java and Oracle timestamp with time zone

Tags: oracle, hibernate, timestamp, ojdbc, offsetdatetime

I'm trying to save two dates in Oracle with hibernate. both dates have the same timestamps in the moscow time zone: 2005-10-30T02:00+03:00[Europe/Moscow] and 2005-10-30T02:00+04:00[Europe/Moscow] ("Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 MSK 2005" and "Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 MSD 2005"). the dates are separated in time by one hour and are associated with the transition to winter/summer time.

I created the table in Oracle:

```
create table TMP
(
    ID    LONG,
    TS    TIMESTAMP,
    TSLTZ TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE,
    TSTZ  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

and entity in my module:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tmp")
public class DateTimeOracle {

    private Long id;
    private ZonedDateTime ts;
    private ZonedDateTime tsltz;
    private ZonedDateTime tstz;

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getTs() {
        return ts;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime setTs(ZonedDateTime ts) {
        this.ts = ts;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getTsltz() {
        return tsltz;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime setTsltz(ZonedDateTime tsltz) {
        this.tsltz = tsltz;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getTstz() {
        return tstz;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime setTstz1(ZonedDateTime tstz) {
        this.tstz = tstz;
    }
}
```

In entity, all fields are initialized by a single date.
After saving, both dates in Oracle have the same values and look like:

ts = 2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000

TSLTZ = 2005-10-29 23:00:00.000000

TSTZ = 2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000 +04:00

Why does oracle keep the same value for different dates (including offset +04:00)? Is there any way to fix this?

P.S. Postgres stores the date correctly. One with an offset +03:00, the other with an offset +04:00 (2005-10-29 23:00:00.000000 and 2005-10-29 22:00:00.000000, respectively).

**Update**

This is how i create the dates:

```
Date dt2 = new Date(1130623200000L); //2005-10-29 23:00:00 +04:00
Date dt3 = new Date(1130626800000L); //2005-10-29 23:00:00 +03:00
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(dt2.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()); // My zone is MSK
ZonedDateTime zdt3 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(dt3.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()); // My zone is MSK
OffsetDateTime odt2 = zdt2.toOffsetDateTime();
OffsetDateTime odt3 = zdt3.toOffsetDateTime();
```

If I not use Hibernate and use jdbc directly, the situation doesn't change.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("<oracle_url>",
                        "<username>", "<password>");
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into tmp (id, TSTZ1, TSTZ2) values (200, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pstmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dt2.getTime()));
pstmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dt3.getTime()));
int z1 = pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt.close();
conn.close();
```

**Update2**

If I save OffsetDateTime via the jdbc driver in timestamp with local timezone or in timestamp with time zone, then everything is fine.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into tmp (TSLTZ1, TSLTZ2, TSTZ1, TSTZ2) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");    
pstmt.setObject(1, odt2);
pstmt.setObject(2, odt3);
pstmt.setObject(3, odt2);
pstmt.setObject(4, odt3);
```

I see in DB:

```
2005-10-29 22:00:00.000000  2005-10-29 23:00:00.000000  2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000 +04:00   2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000 +03:00
```

But if I save ZonedDateTime, then the values in timestamp with local timezone are correct, but in timestamp with time zone are incorrect.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into tmp (TSLTZ1, TSLTZ2, TSTZ1, TSTZ2) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");    
pstmt.setObject(1, zdt2);
pstmt.setObject(2, zdt3);
pstmt.setObject(3, zdt2);
pstmt.setObject(4, zdt3);
```

In DB I see:

```
2005-10-29 22:00:00.000000  2005-10-29 23:00:00.000000  2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000 +04:00   2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000 +04:00
```

The last two values are incorrect.

Comment: Why do you use data type `LONG`? It is deprecated for ages.

Comment: This is a test case, id is used to distinguish different inserts

Comment: I don't think `java.sql.Date` is the right class. `java.sql.Timestamp` might be better.

Comment: Your question is really confusing. Please make a clear statement **for one record**: What did you insert? What is the result (using proper output format)? And what do you expect instead? Then, if needed do the same for a second value.

Comment: Unixtime `1130623200000` is `2005-10-29 22:00:00+00:00` which is `2005-10-30 02:00:00+04:00` at Moscow time zone. Unixtime `1130626800000` yields to `2005-10-29 23:00:00+00:00` respective `2005-10-30 02:00:00+03:00`

Comment: What do you get from `select SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual`?

Comment: select SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual;  -- UTC
When I save to database 1130623200000, then in database i see 2005-10-29 23:00:00 (column type: timestamp with local time zone). But I should see 2005-10-29 22:00:00

Comment: Did you run `select SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual` from Java/Hibernate?

Comment: `But I don't understand why this works wrong:

pstmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dt2.getTime()));` - You should not waste your time analysing this. The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). You have already mentioned: `If I save the date as

pstmt.setObject(1, odt2);
then all is ok!`. Note that `java.util.Date` does not have timezone infromation.

Answer (score 4):

Some explanations about the Oracle TIMESTAMP data types:

- `TIMESTAMP`: Does not store any timezone information. If you enter a timestamp with time zone then the time zone information is simply truncated and lost.
- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`: Stores the timestamp with time zone information (i.e. either as named region or as UTC-Offset) as you insert the timestamp into database.
- `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`: Timestamp is stored as `DBTIMEZONE` (recommended and usually `UTC`). The timestamp is **always and only** displayed in the current user session `SESSIONTIMEZONE`. Thus it does not display any time zone information, because by definition this is always your local time zone.

Which one should I use?

It depends on your requirements - of course.

With `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` you don't have to care about any settings of your client, the time is always shown as local time. The time is stored in `DBTIMEZONE`, thus you lose the original inserted time zone.

Be aware, when you create an index on `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. It is not possible to create an index directly on such column. Instead Oracle creates a virtual column for `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TSTZ)` and creates the index on this virtual column. You should pay attention to this when you develop your queries.

**Update**

You have quite a special situation. When you insert `TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow'` then this time is ambiguous, it could mean `2005-10-30 02:00:00+03:00` or `2005-10-30 02:00:00+04:00`

Take this example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 00:00:00 Europe/Moscow' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 
    'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM TZD tzr') AS ts
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;

+--------------------------------------------+
|TS                                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
|2005-10-30 01:00:00 +04:00 MSD Europe/Moscow|
|2005-10-30 02:00:00 +04:00 MSD Europe/Moscow|
|2005-10-30 02:00:00 +03:00 MSK Europe/Moscow|
|2005-10-30 03:00:00 +03:00 MSK Europe/Moscow|
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Have a look at [TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-5BC5D2C1-6506-49BE-8177-F743A46FDC09)

> To eliminate the ambiguity of boundary cases when the time switches from Standard Time to Daylight Saving Time, use both the TZR format element and the corresponding TZD format element. The TZD format element is an abbreviation of the time zone region with Daylight Saving Time information included. Examples are PST for U. S. Pacific Standard Time and PDT for U. S. Pacific Daylight Time. The following specification ensures that a Daylight Saving Time value is returned:
>
> ```
> TIMESTAMP '1999-10-29 01:30:00 America/Los_Angeles PDT'
> ```
>
> If you do not add the TZD format element, and the datetime value is ambiguous, then Oracle Database returns an error if you have the `ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME` session parameter set to `TRUE`. If `ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME` is set to `FALSE` (the default value), then Oracle Database interprets the ambiguous datetime as Standard Time.

Note, time zone `+04:00` or `+03:00` is **not equal** to `Europe/Moscow`. Timezone `Europe/Moscow` considers daylight-saving-times (when it was still used in Russia about 10 years ago) but `+04:00`/`+03:00` does not.

Sorry, I never used hibernate, so I don't know how this framework handles such data. I am not familiar with Java either. Maybe the Daylight Saving Time information is not supported.

I can just guess, class `java.sql.Date` and method `setDate` refers to `DATE` data type in Oracle. As already stated, better use `java.sql.Timestamp`and `setTimestamp`.

The `DATE` data type does not support any time zone information. If you try to insert a `DATE` value into a `TIMESTAMP WITH [LOCAL] TIME ZONE` column then Oracle actually does

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(<your DATE value> AS TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but the question was different. Why does Oracle keep the same value for two different dates?

Comment: What are the "two different dates" and the result? I am quite sure when you insert `2005-10-30T02:00+03:00` then TSTZ is certainly not `2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000 +04:00`

Comment: I thought the same, but when I insert 2005-10-30T02:00+03:00 then TSTZ I see in database 2005-10-30 02:00:00.000000 +04:00.
You can try to save the specified dates in the database yourself.

Comment: Edit: I save not 2005-10-30T02:00+03:00, but zdt3 and odt3 (see the topic at the top)

Comment: You are right, but when I save dates from Java, then I have wrong values in database, even if i use jdbc directly without hibernate.

Comment: I don't use Java either. Sorry, there is nothing I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You conditions are very special, let's try to lighten it a bit.

Unix time 1130623200 is `2005-10-29 22:00:00 UTC`

- In Moscow time this is `2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow`, however this is ambiguous.
  It could be
- either `2005-10-30 02:00:00 +04:00 Europe/Moscow MSD`
- or `2005-10-30 02:00:00 +03:00 Europe/Moscow MSK`

Unix time 1130626800 is `2005-10-29 23:00:00 UTC`

- In Moscow time this is `2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow`, however this is ambiguous.
  It could be
- either `2005-10-30 02:00:00 +04:00 Europe/Moscow MSD`
- or `2005-10-30 02:00:00 +03:00 Europe/Moscow MSK`

According to Oracle Documentation the ambiguous `TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow'` let to standard time, i.e. `2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow MSK +03:00` (as it was in 2005!)

Be aware, in 2005 Moscow standard time was `MSK => +03:00`. In 2011, the Russian government proclaimed that daylight saving time would in future be observed all year round, thus effectively displacing standard time. I.e. today Moscow standard time is `MSK => +04:00` which was called `MSD` before 2011.

Verify with

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-29 22:00:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM tzr TZD') AS TS_1_UTC,
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-29 23:00:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM tzr TZD') AS TS_2_UTC,
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM tzr TZD') AS TS,
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow MSK', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM tzr TZD') AS TS_MSK,
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow MSD', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM tzr TZD') AS TS_MSD
FROM dual
```

| TS_1_UTC | TS_2_UTC | TS | TS_MSK | TS_MSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-10-30 02:00:00 +04:00 Europe/Moscow MSD | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 +03:00 Europe/Moscow MSK | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 +03:00 Europe/Moscow MSK | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 +03:00 Europe/Moscow MSK | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 +04:00 Europe/Moscow MSD |

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow';

SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-29 22:00:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow' AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD') AS TS_1_UTC,
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-29 23:00:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow' AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD') AS TS_2_UTC,
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow' AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD') AS TS,
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow MSK' AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD') AS TS_MSK,
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2005-10-30 02:00:00 Europe/Moscow MSD' AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD') AS TS_MSD
FROM dual
```

| TS_1_UTC | TS_2_UTC | TS | TS_MSK | TS_MSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-10-30 02:00:00 MSD | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 MSK | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 MSK | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 MSK | 2005-10-30 02:00:00 MSD |

I think Oracle does it absolutely correct, not matter if you have `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. But you have to check **carefully** what is actually inserted into table and how you display it.